# Is it possible to return a struct from a Linq2Entities query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

This code generates a runtime error:

```
struct MyStruct {
  public int ID;
  public string Desc;
}
...
var q = db.MyTable.Select(t => new MyStruct { ID = t.ID, Desc = t.Desc });
```

The error happens because there's no parameterless constructor for the struct.  But I can't use an explicit constructor, because there's no SQL translation for that.

My first question is why this doesn't generate a compile-time error - the compiler knows that `MyStruct` is a struct and that I can't use an object initializer on this non-existent parameterless constructor.

But the more significant question is, is this a known limitation of Linq2Entities, that you have to use classes rather than structs?

Comment: Your struct looks like that it has an implicit/default parameterless constructor, why could such an exception be thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) The compiler doesn't know what LINQ To Entities does, and it shouldn't.

2) [Yes, it is known](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-few-things-you-can-t-do-with-ef-queries-which-you-won-t-find-out-until-runtime/).

A fix though:

```
var q = db.MyTable
    //do your processing here (Where, Any, Join, whatever)
    .ToList() //or AsEnumerable or ToArray
    .Select(t => new MyStruct { ID = t.ID, Desc = t.Desc });
```